# Splitting data set to create validation and test subsets

Tags: validation, testing, split, subset, partition

I have a data set with classes (1..7) and have to create validation and testing subsets from that data set, taking 50% of each class. (So half of class 1 should be assigned as training and half should be assigned as validation.) How can I write the code?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I actually couldn't make a good start. What I was able to do was to create a matrix for each class by writing: glass1 = glass_n[1:70,] (because the first class is from 1st to 70th row.) Then I will use test_g1 = sample(x,length(glass1)/2) but then I don't know how I can differentiate the validation data.

Comment: Now I thought about creating random numbers for glass1 data frame. So i will create the test data set by taking the row with values 1 to 35. But what concerns me is that I cannot use this method in any other data set. It is not applicable at all!